# Ubuntu Gnome Live USB won't display anything after boot

Tags: gnome, 15.04, ubuntu-gnome

I recently built a computer and am trying to install Ubuntu Gnome on it. I can get to the boot menu just fine, but after boot, my monitors switch off. This happens either when booting to the Gnome environment or just trying to install without booting to the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

Apparently, it was trying to load in such a way that couldn't display on my video card (Nvidia). I had to append "nomodeset" to the command line for launching.